# Z-Order in Shared Element Activity Transition Animations

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am doing some basic shared element activity transition animations with code similar to this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AnActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat options =
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                Pair.create(vBackground, "background"),
                Pair.create(vImage, "image"),
                Pair.create(vName, "name"),
                Pair.create(vDistance, "distance")
        );
startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

Can I change the Z-order that the animation assigns to the views?

The reason is that some of the views are hidden by the others during the animation, even though in both activity layouts this is not the case. Somewhere in the transition code, the Z-order of the views gets changed.

I have tried reordering the `Pair.create(...)` lines, but to no great success.

Comment: Related: [Shared Element Transition (Foreground/Background) Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348018/shared-element-transition-foreground-background-issue) (but can't close as duplicate as no accepted answer there)

Comment: Solution : ViewGroupTree

# Solution  
    level 0 : Activity_layout  
    level 2 : Fragment_layout

    item 1::Hierarchy : Constraint -> vImage
    item 1::Hierarchy : Constraint -> Constraint -> Linear -> Background


With this, the layout are Z index order are messed up.
You have to use the same level of deep for each of your view to get a, expected call